# Question about Lucy Lawless playing two characters in Hercules: The Legendary Journeys

Tags: actors, hercules

In the show "[**Hercules: The Legendary Journeys**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules:_The_Legendary_Journeys)", actress [Lucy Lawless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_Lawless) (best known as Xena) plays both the infamous Xena as well as Lyla - a human woman married to a centaur.

Lyla only appeared in two episodes, and in her second appearance (S02E05 "Outcast") the

> woman is brutally slain by bigoted townspeople who disapproved of her mixed marriage.

At this time, the Xena character was being spun off into her own series ([Xena: Warrior Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xena:_Warrior_Princess)). The timing leaves me with two questions:

**Were these two events related, and was the physical resemblance of the characters ever mentioned in-universe (seeing as how Hercules & Iolaus knew both women)?**

Comment: IIRC someone does ask an offhand question about it, but I recall who or when.

Comment: Don't Hercules and Iolaus know pretty much every other character?

Comment: Out of universe relation: Lucy Lawless has a really, really good agent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In-universe, Xena has a number of known lookalikes

This is revisited in-universe in the sense that, on *Xena: Princess Warrior*, Xena has several additional lookalikes.

In addition to Lyla from *Herculues*, in *Xena: Princess Warrior* there are:

- **Leah**, a Hestian priestess first seen in "Warrior ... Priestess ... Tramp"
- **Lysia**, an Amazonian in Queen Hippolyta's tribe, seen in "Hercules and the Amazon Women"
- **Meg**, a prostitute first seen in "Warrior ... Princess ... Tramp"
- **Melinda Pappas**, an archeologist in the 20th century episode "The Xena Scrolls"
- **Annie Day**, a Xena fan seen in "Deja Vu All Over Again" and "Soul Possession"
- **Diana**, a princess first seen in "Warrior ... Princess"

All are played by Lucy Lawless but are distinct characters from Xena (yet still visibly identical to her, i.e. their appearances are not obscured by make-up or other costuming).

For instance, here is Lysia:

[image]

As another example, here is Diana:

[image]

The fact that these characters look identical to Xena is actually a plot point in *Xena: Princess Warrior*.  For instance, the *Hercules and Xena* Wiki mentions the following about Diana:

> She is a Xena lookalike, which has gotten her into a few tough situations over the years.
>
> In both of her appearances, she was the target for assassins, which was the reason why Xena protected her.
>
> ...Diana's father asks Xena for help with his daughter's marriage etc. Xena takes over the role of Diana, and Diana takes Xena's role...

([Source](http://hercxena.wikia.com/wiki/Diana))

Whether the idea of having lookalikes was in place before Lyla's character was conceived or whether it was a way of addressing the fact that Xena and Lyla are played by the same actress is unclear.  However, the issue of Xena and Lyla's resemblance was eventually brought up explicitly in *Hercules* :

> In "Outcast", Salmoneus and Hercules comment on Lyla's resemblance to Xena as a throwaway joke: though "As Darkness Falls" was filmed and aired before Xena's first appearance, "Outcast" was produced after audiences were already quite familiar with the warrior princess.

([Source](http://hercxena.wikia.com/wiki/Lyla))

Comment: Lysia is played by Lucy Lawless, but I wouldn't describe her as a lookalike.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm : Thanks for the added biographical details on the lookalikes.  Lysia is also described as a lookalike [here](http://hercxena.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Xena_Look-alikes).  Also, from her picture above, she looks awfully more like Xena than Lyla does in my opinion! :-) (Compare [Lyla](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/hercxena/images/3/36/Lyla_darkness_falls.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100625202306) to Lysia above.)